# Scalable boxes positioned centered

Tags: html, positioning, image-scaling, css

I am looking for a solution to position several boxes (one image in each box) of different sizes and make them scalable all together. All of the boxes will be centered in the middle of the webpage.

```
   background-image:url('http://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/images/cube2.jpg');
   background-size: 100%;
```

http://i49.tinypic.com/18ir5z.jpg

(A visual example)

The circle's purpose is to assure the scaling and resizing. If the site, the four boxes is scaled down the circle would follow. See the circle as four small images in the four boxes. Hope I'm making myself clear.

Comment: That's not how this works. Try something, get stuck, then show us what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: I have tried with a lot of things. Can't get it to work. The resizing part is not an issue, though is the fixed positioning with a bunch of content that I want to fit together, see example http://jsfiddle.net/Xfpp7/10/ :)